# How can spyder in the base environment access the package installed in a virtual environment?

Tags: python, anaconda, geopandas, virtual-environment

I use Anaconda as my platform to write Python code for data analysis. And I have successfully installed Pytorch, GDAL, etc. in the base environment, but the package 'geopandas' failed to be installed. I hence installed 'geopandas' in a virtual environment, say 'geo-env', in which Pytorch, GDAL, etc. were not installed.

Now I want to use the packages in both the base and the virtual environment in spyder (only installed in the base environment), but the package 'geopandas' in 'geo-env' cannot be loaded. How can I wwork out? Are there advices?

Comment: I don't think it's possible to do that, you have to install all the packages in the same environment that you're going to use in the script at the same time.

Comment: Thank you. If what you said is true, then how can we use two packages at the same time if they cannot be installed in the same environment?